# getting error: Error : Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1

Tags: validation-rule

> If((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c) = "High-Tech"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c) = "RCL"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c) = "T&H"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c) = "Insurance"),"Delivery Unit 1",IF((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c) = "International"),"Delivery Unit 1","n/a")))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below formula you don't require the = comparator

```
If((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "High-Tech"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "RCL"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "T&H"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "Insurance"),"Delivery Unit 1",IF((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "International"),"Delivery Unit 1","n/a")))))
```

Comment: Your parentheses are in the wrong order for ISPICKVAL.

Answer (score 1):

`ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c) = "High-Tech")` Your method format is incorrect

```
ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "High-Tech")
```

this is the correct format. So you need to modify your rule formula.

```
If((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "High-Tech"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "RCL"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "T&H"),"Delivery Unit 1",if((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "Insurance"),"Delivery Unit 1",IF((ISPICKVAL(Business_Unit__c, "International"),"Delivery Unit 1","n/a")))))
```